# Mongo time-series inserts using c# produce exception after short time

Tags: c#, mongodb, time-series

I want to test if mongo db can have a collection up to 50 000 000 000.

So I insert 10K elements every second using method:

```
public async Task InsertManyAsync(List<DBRoutLine> list)
{
  await _collRouts.InsertManyAsync(list);
}
```

Data looks like this:

```
namespace DbLayer.Models
{

  public class DBRoutLineMeta
  {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int counter { get; set; }
  }

  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class DBRoutLine
  {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DBRoutLineMeta meta { get; set; } = new DBRoutLineMeta();

    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public string some_data { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

id members not required actually but I have them, just for testing.

So I've got exception like this:
"A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. WriteErrors: [ { Category : "DuplicateKey", Code : 11000, Message : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: TSTest.system.buckets.TSTable dup key: { _id: ObjectId('634e87301297fa65b7df9923') }" } ]."

after sometime. It can be also like this:

"time-series insert failed: TSTest.TSTable :: caused by :: Expected

And it will never recover from error even if I recreate connection to mongo server. Only application restart helps to insert records again.

Test code:

```
using DbLayer.Models;
using DbLayer.Services;
using MongoDB.Bson;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var service = new RoutService();

try
{
  CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;


  var list = new List<DBRoutLine>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    DBRoutLine line = new DBRoutLine();
    list.Add(line);
  }

  Task task = Task.Run(async () => {
    int max_counter = await service.GetMaxCount();

    bool recover = false;

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      try
      {
        if (!recover)
        {
          foreach (DBRoutLine line in list)
          {
            line.meta.counter = ++max_counter;
            line.id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
            line.meta.id = line.id;
          }
        }        

        var t1 = DateTime.Now;

        await service.InsertManyAsync(list);

        var t2 = DateTime.Now;
        max_counter = await service.GetMaxCount();
        var t3 = DateTime.Now;

        Console
        .WriteLine(
          $"{max_counter}->Insert:{(int)(t2 - t1).TotalMilliseconds}, GetMax:{(int)(t3 - t2).TotalMilliseconds}");

        recover = false;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        recover = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        service = new RoutService();

        max_counter = await service.GetMaxCount();
      }      
    }
  
  }, token);

  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop emulation\n");
  Console.ReadKey();
  tokenSource.Cancel();

  Task.WaitAll(task);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Service code:

```
using DbLayer.Models;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DbLayer.Services
{
  public class RoutService:IDisposable
  {
    private readonly IMongoCollection<DBRoutLine> _collRouts;
    private readonly MongoClient _mongoClient;
    private readonly string CollName = "TSTable";
    public RoutService(
    )
    {
      var ConnectionString = "mongodb://mongoservice:27017";
      _mongoClient = new MongoClient(
        ConnectionString);

      var mongoDatabase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(
          "TSTest");

      var filter = new BsonDocument("name", CollName);
      var options = new ListCollectionNamesOptions { Filter = filter };

      if (!mongoDatabase.ListCollectionNames(options).Any())
      {
        var createOptions = new CreateCollectionOptions();

        var timeField = nameof(DBRoutLine.timestamp);
        var metaField = nameof(DBRoutLine.meta);
        createOptions.TimeSeriesOptions =
          new TimeSeriesOptions(timeField, metaField, TimeSeriesGranularity.Minutes);


        mongoDatabase.CreateCollection(
          CollName,
          createOptions);
      }

      _collRouts =
        mongoDatabase.GetCollection<DBRoutLine>(
          CollName
        );


      CreateIndexes();
    }

    private void CreateIndexes()
    {
      {
        IndexKeysDefinition<DBRoutLine> keys =
          new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<DBRoutLine>()
          .Descending(d => d.meta.counter);

        var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<DBRoutLine>(
          keys, new CreateIndexOptions()
          { Name = "counter" }
        );

        _collRouts.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
      }
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////
      {
        IndexKeysDefinition<DBRoutLine> keys =
          new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<DBRoutLine>()
          .Ascending(d => d.meta.id);

        var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<DBRoutLine>(
          keys, new CreateIndexOptions()
          { Name = "id" }
        );

        _collRouts.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
      }
    }

    public async Task InsertManyAsync(List<DBRoutLine> list)
    {
      await _collRouts.InsertManyAsync(list);
    }

    public async Task<int> GetMaxCount()
    {
      var last = await _collRouts
        .Find(i=> i.meta.counter > 0)
        .SortByDescending( i => i.meta.counter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
      if (last == null)
      {
        return 0;
      }
      return last.meta.counter;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      
    }
  }
}
```

project repository:
github.com/pruginkad/TestMongo

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Does it ever create any records?  It seems you are specifying a field in class DBRoutLine called id of type string.  I can't see where you are setting a specific value, but since you have decorated it with `[BsonId]` I believe it maps t the _id field which must be unique.  Try setting it to a unique value.

Comment: https://github.com/pruginkad/TestMongo

Comment: no id is not a problem. In time-series collection it's not required actually. I even deleted it to try but still the same problem. I can insert about 10 000 000 records before the exception occurs. So the code works, the problem in mongo I believe or in some settings which required for connection. Or c# driver bug, otherwise mongo developer could run into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the bug. I changed timestamp only once when I created List of documents.

in this code:

```
      foreach (DBRoutLine line in list)
      {
        line.meta.counter = ++max_counter;
        line.id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        line.meta.id = line.id;
        line.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;//missing line
      }
```

I had to update timestamp, my mistake.

Anyway it's kind of strange that exception happen after every 17M documents and disappear after restart of mongo db